# Angular 6 Custom Element Output EventEmitter

Tags: angular, custom-element

I have an element with an output event emitter and I cannot figure out how to catch the event. I get this error:

> "Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'EventEmitter'."

this is the output

```
  @Output() closeMarkers = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

And this is how I add the element to the component:

```
              createPopupComponentWithMessage(latitude, longitude, city) {
                    const popupEl: NgElement & WithProperties<MarkerNewComponent> = document.createElement('new-marker') as any;
                      //Set MarkerNewComponent input vars
                      popupEl.city=city;
                      popupEl.latitude=latitude;
                      popupEl.longitude=longitude;
                      popupEl.closeMarkers = this.testOutput ;
                      popupEl.addEventListener('closed', () =>  document.body.removeChild(popupEl));

                      // Add to the DOM
                      document.body.appendChild(popupEl);
                    return popupEl;
                  }

        testOutput (){
               console.log('test output');
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the parent component, you should have a tag for your children component

for example

PARENT.COMPONENT.HTML

```
<div> myInformation</div>
<myChild></myChild>
```

to catch the event from your child you must do it like this

```
<div> myInformation</div>
<myChild (closeMarkers)="myParentFunctionToHandleIt($event)" ></myChild>
```

here is the documentation : https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

EDIT : in the parent component, you can specify the type of the event

PARENT.COMPONENT.TS

```
myParentFunctionToHandleIt(value: MyCustomType) {
//your way to handle your event
}
```

Comment: if it's not what you want to do, can you make a stackblitz so we can understand your problem ;) @John

Comment: I dont have the tag on the parent component because I'm using angular custom elements to build a custom leaflet marker

Comment: so you want to notify your application when someone click on the marker?

Comment: I also use Leaflet in my current project, to bind function to a marker I use the function L.divIcon to create my marker and inject some code inside the html (for example a click function) i don 't know if it's what you're looking for
(and in the click function you can bind your eventEmitter call)

Comment: My goal is tu use a component inside a leaflet marker and it's already working, i just want to emit an event ind the children component and catch it in the parent one. In the example i can set input vars, but i cannot make output working

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz so I can try to help you ;)?

Comment: I figure it out with this   popupEl.addEventListener('closeMarkers', () =>  {
            console.log('closeMarkers')
          });

Comment: Thank you for your help